# Select average of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, average

I have a table named `tblPurchaseSub`. In this table I have the columns `Barcode` that can be in several lines, `ItemName`, `PPriceID`. I want to get the `Barcode`, `ItemName` and the average price of `PPriceID` column.

```
Barcode | ItemName  | PPriceID
----------------------------
2323      Item 1      12
2424      Item 2      14
2121      Item 3      15
2323      Item 1      11
2323      Item 1      13
2424      Item 2      15
```

I have tried: `Select Barcode, ItemName, AVG(PPriceID) from tblPurchaseSub group by BarCode`

but it seems this is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, every column in the `SELECT` clause that is not within an aggregate function (such as `AVG()`) must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

So to make your code a valid aggregation query, you need to add column `ItemName` to the `group by` clause:

```
select Barcode, ItemName, AVG(PPriceID) avgPPriceID
from tblPurchaseSub 
group by BarCode, ItemName
```

This gives you one row per `(Barcode, ItemName)` tuple, along with the average `PPriceID` of the corresponding rows in the original table.